# How to stop Vim from opening a new window when opening file in readonly window?

Tags: vim

I'm using the [MiniBufExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) plugin to display a list of open buffers at the top of my Vim window. I'm also using the [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) plugin to open files, in case that matters.

The problem is that, if I have the `-MiniBufExplorer-` window focused, and I open a file, the window will split:

```
MMMMMM     MMMMMM
AAAAAA     AAAAAA    M = -MiniBufExplorer-
AAAAAA --> AAAAAA    A = some open file
AAAAAA     BBBBBB    B = the file I just opened
AAAAAA     BBBBBB
```

My guess is that Vim determines that the `-MiniBufExplorer-` window should not be used to open a file in, and decides to create a new window to hold the new buffer.

Instead, I want file `B` simply to be opened in the window previously occupied by `A`. If `A`'s window has focus, this happens the way I want it to; it's just when `-MiniBufExplorer-` is focused that I get the unwanted split.

I'm not proficient at Vim scripting, and not very familiar with the windowing/buffers model, so I don't know how difficult it is to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem. Have you solved this by any chance?

Comment: @Edan Maor: No, unfortunately not...

Comment: Just tried version 6.3.2 of the minibuf plugin on MacVim 7.2 (52): http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=3640 and it works fine.  Can you give more info about the version of vim that you are using?

Comment: Vim 7.2 on Ubuntu Maverick, minibuf 6.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MiniBufExplorer plugin is good to use.

I find some bugs of this plugin. I delete this plugin now, try others.

PS: I don't use such plugins,  just ctrl+o, ctrl+i :)

when open many files, this plugin is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an abbreviation for command-line mode like this:

`cabbrev ne new +only`

what this does is to make an alias, then when you type `ne` vim executes `new +only`.
`new +only` creates a new document and executes `only` on it which results in a full window new document.

You'd better put that on your .vimrc and to prevent a remap you use `cnoreabbrev`

`cnoreabbrev ne new +only`